# zope template namespaces gone?

Tags: python, zope

Where can I find the zope namespaces for my templates?  I setup a pyramid project using SQLAlchemy + URL dispatch + Chameleon templates.  These URLs don't exist anymore...

http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/tal

http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/metal

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks...I guess that's the answer.  If this were an answer I would have checked it. :-)

Comment: The URLs *never* existed. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TAL specification says:

> This is not a URL, but merely a unique identifier. Do not expect a browser to resolve it successfully.

http://wiki.zope.org/ZPT/TALSpecification14

Comment: And of course it is true of *all* namespaces, not just Zope's, that it need not be an actual URL.